# AJAX POST REST call generates CORS error

Tags: javascript, rest, cors

My SharePoint client JavaScript is calling an external REST API URL, using the code pattern below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'https:\\theexternal.domain......,
  contentType: "application/json",
  headers: {
      'Accept' : "application/json, */*;",
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)  
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
      .
      .
      .
  }),
   success: success,
   error: error
});
```

We have changed the `web.xml` configuration file of the external domain server, to include the code:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

as per the directions on https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter.

However, the AJAX POST is still returning the error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https:\theexternal.domain...... This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

What have we missed?

Answer (score 7):

Modern browsers block cross-domain JavaScript requests by design - it's a security feature, not a bug. There exists workarounds for this, which can be used only if you have an access to configure the external domain:

The `theexternal.domain` source needs to explicitly enable your request by including `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteMakingTheCall.domain` to the HTTP header.

There exists more broader explanation of this in e.g. these sources:

- [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310450/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-concept)
- [“Cross-Origin Request Blocked” - how to bypass for REST queries](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153975/cross-origin-request-blocked-how-to-bypass-for-rest-queries) (includes another suggested workaround)
- [Cross-Origin Request Blocked when accessing O365 Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753675/cross-origin-request-blocked-when-accessing-o365-rest-api) (O365 scenario with suggested workarounds)

---

Edit: Using Apache Tomcat as in your case, the configuration might be a bit different. The "minimal configuration" as you seem to have used based on your question should be expanded to include an `<init-param>`-block for `cors.allowed.origins` to actually allow the request coming from outside. So, the complete configuration would be the following:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, I'd strongly suggest to replace the `*` to only include the SharePoint's host. If you have multiple hosts to be added, do it by comma-separating - e.g. `sp-host1.com, sp-host2.com`

Comment: According to the tomcat website, if I've set up the CorsFilter definition, it draws in all the subsequent defaults: that include: cors.allowed.origins 
A list of origins that are allowed to access the resource. A * can be specified to enable access to resource from any origin. Otherwise, a whitelist of comma separated origins can be provided. Eg:  http://www.w3.org, https://www.apache.org. Defaults: * (Any origin is allowed to access the resource).

So, my understanding is that this code will allow theexternal.domain to accept '*' as an origin. Or have I missed something?

Comment: So, is this filter automatically adding in cors.allowed.origins : * to the headers of any incoming request? Or is it telling the server to just ignore any headers as everything is allowed to come through?

Comment: `*` enables any origin to request the source. I'll update in a minute the answer to give a suggestion.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help. Yes, this is the solution. Works wonderfully. Many, many thanks!

Comment: @southskies glad to help. One more thing: you should mark it as an answer to promote the visibility for others looking for help with the same issue.

Comment: @southskies Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answer as accepted in case it helped and solved your issue to be helpful for future visitors. Thank You!

Comment: Yes, I have upvoted it... hopefully this has worked!

Comment: @southskies what was meant here, was that an answer that successfully answers to your original questions by solving it should be **marked as an answer**. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Both of the short articles should be understood and respected while using SharePoint.SE.